# Connection To The Database Failed on install dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I try to install dotnetnuke 7. I created an user that access to dnn database and in properties of sql server set the server authentication to  sqlserver and windows authentication .But when browse website show this message :Connection To The Database Failed

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the database using SQL Server Management Studio using the same credentials that you specify in DNN.  That might help you identify what you are doing wrong.

You'll want to verify that the SQL Server accepts connections from the web server, assuming that they are not on the same machine.